# Android Wear Watch Face not being installed

Tags: android, wear-os

I must be missing something simple. I have developed a watch face, but when I build the mobile apk it never makes it's way to the watch. If I build the wear apk, everything works as expected.

Things I have checked so far.

Permissions: I have set the permissions in both the wear and mobile AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Gradle build: The wear app is referenced in the build.gradle of the mobile app.

```
wearApp project(':wear')
```

Things to note, The mobile app does nothing other than be a carrier for the wear app. It does not have any Activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate a **signed** APK and install it manually on your phone with the Android Wear companion app.

Comment: I have generated the signed APK, and installed it via adb (and through the play store beta service). The watch face never shows up in the Android Wear app, or the watch. Does the mobile app have to perform any action other than reference the wear app in the build.gradle?

Comment: My apologies, I was using Android Studio to install it, I manually installed it via adb and all is fine. Thank you very much Fredrick Schweiger.